# EOF from standard input is displayed in standard output

Tags: c, macos, unix

I am doing a few tests with reading from standard input and writing in standard output, and something is really bothering me.

When I try to write a single character followed by a \n, the "D" from the **EOF** (I presume) is printing after the character.

Here is what happens in the terminal :

```
 >./myprog
 sometext I enter
 "Ctrl + D"
 jD
 j
 >
```

and here is the code :

```
#define BUF_SIZE 4096

void    read_std_in()
{
    int     ret;
    char    buf[BUF_SIZE + 1];

    while ((ret = read(0, buf, BUF_SIZE)))
    {
        buf[ret] = '\0';
        // Concatenating buffer with some other string, not important here.
    }
    write(1, "j", 1);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    write(1, "j", 1);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
}
```

As you can see, the first "j" gets a "D" from nowhere.

If I try displaying more than 1 character for the forst line, the problem doesn't appear :

```
 >./myprog
 sometext I enter
 "Ctrl + D"
 jj
 j
 >
```

And if I put no char (just \n) I get :

```
 >./myprog
 sometext I enter
 "Ctrl + D"
 ^D
 j
 >
```

**How can I avoid this behaviour?**

Comment: What is `BUF_SIZE`, please?

Comment: @alk I use 4096. I will edit my post.

Comment: Which UNIX/C-implementation are you using?

Comment: I am working on OS X/??. How to know the C-Implementation?

Comment: C-implementation refers to the compiler and the libc used.

Comment: the function: `read()` can return a negative value when an error occurs.  The code will continue to loop under such conditions.   Strongly suggest using `fgets()` rather than `read()`.

Comment: when there is a I/O error on the call to read(), the the returned value is -1.  then the next line: `buf[ret] = '\0';` will corrupt the stack because the NUL character will be written outside the bounds to 'buf[]'.  This is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: the example, where you enter nothing but a '\n' (which is not a ctrl-D) is not correct. please edit that part of the question to show the actual output

Comment: on linux, I ran the posted code (after supplying a main() and the unistd.h header) and it worked correctly. I entered: "this is some text\n<ctrl-D>" (without the quotes) and it worked correctly

Comment: @user3629249 Did you take the time to read the post and understand the problem before spamming?

Comment: @realUser404,  ?spamming?  Certainly I read/understand the post.  I fully realize the OP was using a different OS.  I did not try to answer the question, I simply stated what I found using the linux OS.  Oh, and I also mentioned a couple of logic problems with the posted code.

Answer (score 5):

I'm getting the same behaviour in OS X/Darwin.

It looks like `^D` is being echoed to the console when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, but without advancing the text cursor. As a result, the first `j` is being placed on top of the `^` character. (You can verify this by changing the first `write(1, "j", 1);` to `write(1, "\33[2Cj", 5);`, which moves the cursor two places to the right before printing `j`.)

I don't think there is any simple way to prevent `^D` from appearing, so you could just ignore it. The `D` isn't added to your input, so it won't cause any problems with the operation of your software.

Alternatively, if you pipe the input to your program, then the problem will go away:

```
./myprog <<<"some text"
```